# Magento2 Out of Stock Assosiated Products not showing in the dropdown options for Configurable Products

Tags: magento, magento2, stock, configurable-product, inventory-management

I am facing an issue with Magento2 and I am not sure whether it's a bug or not. I want to show Out of Stock Assosiated Products in the Configurable Product Dropdown.

In the admin settings, Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Inventory -> Display out of stock products, this is already set to "Yes" but no luck.

I have tried several modules with integrating plugins and did a lot of research on this but could not find any solution for this.

Lets take an example - I have a Configurable Product with Child products Size - S , M , L and for instance L is out of stock. So currently I am able to see S and M in the dropdown options for my configurable product.

I want to see all the 3 Child products with the mark of "Out of Stock" like L - Out of Stock or something like that.

Comment: This is a known issue that requires a code fix rather than change of settings - https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10454

Comment: Yes, i gone through this link but this is related to the swatches. And i dont have Swatches, i have a configurable dropdown with child products, and i was in need to out of stock label inside the dropdown for child products. But good news is that i have figured out the solution, and will post my answer shortly, if anyone need this requirement.

Comment: @hardik please share

Comment: I am also tryin with select dropdown

Answer (score 1):

sorry for the late reply. I was really busy with different projects.

So for this, i used 1 module and did customized that based on my requirements. I am providing you all the files and folders so anyone who needs this, can upload the files.

Created a module - Jworks/ConfigurableProduct so the folder structure will be /app/code/Jworks/ConfigurableProduct

Create a file app/code/Jworks/ConfigurableProduct/registration.php and enter below code -

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * @category Jworks
 * @package ConfigurableProduct
 * @author Jitheesh V O <jitheesh@digitalboutique.co.uk>
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2018 Digital Boutique (http://www.digitalboutique.co.uk/)
 */
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Jworks_ConfigurableProduct',
    __DIR__
);
```

Create a file app/code/Jworks/ConfigurableProduct/composer.json and enter below code -

```
{
  "name": "jworks/module-configurableproduct",
  "description": "Jworks configurableproduct updates",
  "require": {
    "magento/module-catalog": "101.0.*"
  },
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "autoload": {
    "files": [
      "registration.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "Jworks\\ConfigurableProduct\\": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Create a file app/code/Jworks/ConfigurableProduct/etc/module.xml and enter below code -

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Jworks_ConfigurableProduct" setup_version="0.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_ConfigurableProduct" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Create a file app/code/Jworks/ConfigurableProduct/etc/di.xml and enter below code -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
 <preference for="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ConfigurableAttributeData" type="Jworks\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Rewrite\ConfigurableAttributeData" />
</config>
```

Create a file app/code/Jworks/ConfigurableProduct/etc/frontend/di.xml and enter below code -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute\OptionSelectBuilderInterface">
        <plugin name="Magento_ConfigurableProduct_Plugin_Model_ResourceModel_Attribute_InStockOptionSelectBuilder" type="Jworks\ConfigurableProduct\Plugin\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute\InStockOptionSelectBuilder"/>
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\AttributeOptionProvider">
        <plugin name="Magento_ConfigurableProduct_Plugin_Model_AttributeOptionProvider" type="Jworks\ConfigurableProduct\Plugin\Model\AttributeOptionProvider"/>
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable">
    <plugin name="changeAllowProductsBehaviour" type="Jworks\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable\Plugin" sortOrder="10" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Create a file app/code/Jworks/ConfigurableProduct/Plugin/Model/AttributeOptionProvider.php and enter below code -

```
<?php


namespace Jworks\ConfigurableProduct\Plugin\Model;
class AttributeOptionProvider
{

    public function afterGetAttributeOptions(\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\AttributeOptionProvider $subject, array $result)
    {
        $optiondata=array();
        foreach ($result as $option) {  

            if(isset($option['stock_status']) && $option['stock_status']==0){
                $option['option_title']  = $option['option_title'].__(' - uitverkocht');
            }
            $optiondata[]=$option;
        }
        return $optiondata;
    }
}
```

Create a file app/code/Jworks/ConfigurableProduct/Plugin/Model/ResourceModel/Attribute/InStockOptionSelectBuilder.php and enter below code -

```
<?php

namespace Jworks\ConfigurableProduct\Plugin\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute;

use Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\ResourceModel\Stock\Status;
use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute\OptionSelectBuilderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Select;

/**
 * Plugin for OptionSelectBuilderInterface to add stock status filter.
 */
class InStockOptionSelectBuilder
{
    /**
     * CatalogInventory Stock Status Resource Model.
     *
     * @var Status
     */
    private $stockStatusResource;

    /**
     * @param Status $stockStatusResource
     */
    public function __construct(Status $stockStatusResource)
    {
        $this->stockStatusResource = $stockStatusResource;
    }

    /**
     * Add stock status filter to select.
     *
     * @param OptionSelectBuilderInterface $subject
     * @param Select $select
     * @return Select
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function afterGetSelect(OptionSelectBuilderInterface $subject, Select $select)
    {
        $select->joinInner(
            ['stock' => $this->stockStatusResource->getMainTable()],
            'stock.product_id = entity.entity_id',
            ['stock.stock_status']
        );

        return $select;
    }
}
```

Create a file app/code/Jworks/ConfigurableProduct/Model/Rewrite/ConfigurableAttributeData.php and enter below code -

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable\Attribute;

/**
 * Class ConfigurableAttributeData
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class ConfigurableAttributeData
{
    /**
     * Get product attributes
     *
     * @param Product $product
     * @param array $options
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAttributesData(Product $product, array $options = [])
    {
        $defaultValues = [];
        $attributes = [];
        foreach ($product->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributes($product) as $attribute) {
            $attributeOptionsData = $this->getAttributeOptionsData($attribute, $options);
            if ($attributeOptionsData) {
                $productAttribute = $attribute->getProductAttribute();
                $attributeId = $productAttribute->getId();
                $attributes[$attributeId] = [
                    'id' => $attributeId,
                    'code' => $productAttribute->getAttributeCode(),
                    'label' => $productAttribute->getStoreLabel($product->getStoreId()),
                    'options' => $attributeOptionsData,
                    'position' => $attribute->getPosition(),
                ];
                $defaultValues[$attributeId] = $this->getAttributeConfigValue($attributeId, $product);
            }
        }
        return [
            'attributes' => $attributes,
            'defaultValues' => $defaultValues,
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param Attribute $attribute
     * @param array $config
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getAttributeOptionsData($attribute, $config)
    {
        $attributeOptionsData = [];
        foreach ($attribute->getOptions() as $attributeOption) {
            $optionId = $attributeOption['value_index'];
            $attributeOptionsData[] = [
                'id' => $optionId,
                'label' => $attributeOption['label'],
                //'test' => $config[$attribute->getAttributeId()][$optionId],
                'products' => isset($config[$attribute->getAttributeId()][$optionId])
                    ? $config[$attribute->getAttributeId()][$optionId]
                    : [],
            ];
        }
        return $attributeOptionsData;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $attributeId
     * @param Product $product
     * @return mixed|null
     */
    protected function getAttributeConfigValue($attributeId, $product)
    {
        return $product->hasPreconfiguredValues()
            ? $product->getPreconfiguredValues()->getData('super_attribute/' . $attributeId)
            : null;
    }
}
```

Create a file app/code/Jworks/ConfigurableProduct/Model/ConfigurableProduct/Block/Product/View/Type/Configurable/Plugin.php and enter below code -

```
<?php
namespace Jworks\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable;

class Plugin
{
    /**
     * getAllowProducts
     *
     * @param \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable $subject
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function beforeGetAllowProducts($subject)
    {
        if (!$subject->hasData('allow_products')) {
            $products = [];
            $allProducts = $subject->getProduct()->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($subject->getProduct(), null);
            foreach ($allProducts as $product) {
                    $products[] = $product;
            }
            $subject->setData('allow_products', $products);
        }

        return [];
    }

}
```

And after all these, you can run all the commands for installing the Magento2 extension.

I hope anybody can get help with this.

Comment: I think this code will not work, installed and tested.

Comment: I have not tested with swatches. I had a requirement for a dropdown and it worked for me. But it would be really great if we can find solution for swatches as well. Do let me know if you find any solution for swatches

Comment: Hello @Hardik, I got this (http://prntscr.com/mnz2ss) error when i install this module. Please help me to solve this

Comment: @KhooshbuPatel It looks like the namespace in ConfigurableAttributeData.php needs to have \Rewrite\ at the end (so `namespace Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Rewrite;`)

Answer (score 0):

open the file vendor\magento\module-catalog\Helper\Product.php

change

```
protected $_skipSaleableCheck = false;
```

to

```
protected $_skipSaleableCheck = true;
```