# Show out of stock swatches in configurable (Magento 2.2.6)

Tags: magento2

I want to show out of stock product swatches in configure product. In the admin settings, Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Inventory -> Display out of stock products, this is already set to "Yes" but not working.

For example, if i have 3 color in configure product and one of them is out of stock then it should be shown with red strike. But it only shows 2 color of swatches.

I install same version of magento and it's working fine when i set Display out of stock products to yes. Then why it's not working in my current project. Can anyone help me to solve this.

Comment: I also tried to create custom module with the help of  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51726905/magento2-out-of-stock-assosiated-products-not-showing-in-the-dropdown-options-fo  but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

The above one is a known issue for Magento and can be solved partially by installing the below extension.

https://github.com/interjar/configurable-child-visibility

Reference for the Issue can be found at Magento Issue 10454